# Avoid replacement of TaskDefinition with CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I'm automating a PR process that need to create stacks through cloudformation. The problem is that, by definition https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html the old TaskDefinition revision is deleted to make place for the new/updated TaskDefinition. Is there any way to avoid the replacement and do only an update?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to keep old revisions or is your question if you can do an inplace-update to a task definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/update-task-definition.html):

> To update a task definition, create a task definition revision. If the task definition is used in a service, you must update that service to use the updated task definition.

This implies that task definition revisions are immutable and there is no way around creating a new revision.

If you want to retain the old versions of your task definitions, you could try the `UpdateReplacementPolicy` with a value of `Retain`. Maybe it's able to keep the old revisions around. For more details check out the [CloudFormation docs - UpdateReplacePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html).

That would look something like this:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  taskdefinition:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties: {} # Your usual properties here
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!